# Cannot read URL parameter from LWC if 'c__' not added to the link

Tags: lightning-web-components, url, redirect, namespace

I have a salesforce tab that contains a search screen, now some external system is redirecting users to this page. When the external system redirects the user to the salesforce screen it appends a parameter with the URL. The URL looks something like this `https://domainname.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/TabAPI?part=ABC`, when the page is redirected as there is no 'c__' added with the 'part' parameter, it gets cleared and I can not read the state using page reference. What should I do in this situation? The external system is old and 'c__' can not be added from there.

Comment: You need to pass the parameter like `c__part` from the external system instead of `part`

Comment: @RahulGawale I know, I mentioned that in my question.